# The convergence of the binomial expansion

Tags: binomial-theorem

The binomial expansion of $\frac{1}{z-2}$ is $-\frac{1}{2}\sum^\infty_{n=0} (-1)^n \left(\frac{z}{2}\right)$.

Does  this converge for $\left|\frac{z}{2}\right|<2$?

Does $\frac{1}{z} \sum^\infty_{n=0} (-1)^n \left(\frac{2}{z}\right)^n$, converge for $|z|>1$?

Comment: The first for $|z/2|\lt 1$, the second for  $|z|\gt  2$.

Comment: why |z/2|<1 if the pole is at 2?

Comment: The only thing to remember is that the geometric series $a+ar+ar^2+\cdots$ converges iff $|r|\lt1$. But maybe you intended to expand in powers of $z-1$, which would give a different (but still geometric) series.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know where your expanding this series at but here is a good rule to help you:

$|z-\alpha|<|\alpha-\beta|$

Where $\beta$ is the nearest singularity which in this case is $2$. So, if $\alpha$ is the point in which you expanded your binomial series at a point $\alpha$ then the series converges for:

$|z-\alpha|<|\alpha-2|$

Please comment on my post and tell me where you are expanding your binomial series at, then I'll solve it further.

Comment: The original question is find the Laurent series expansion of $f(z)=\frac{2z-5}{(z-2)(z-3)}$ in the disk $0 \leq |z| <2$